# NSNotifications from web

Tags: ios, notifications, nsnotifications

Is it possible create NSNotifications in app and then from any form (apple.com) send push notifications to apps users? How can I do it?

Comment: What are you asking for? Sending "notifications" from one user (app) to others (app) using a server? Or just sending push notifications to users? Either way: google for it or search on SO, there plenty of tutorials or even services offering this functionality.

Comment: I want as admin sent notifications to users of my app with custom text or link

Comment: So: build your own server (google for "push notification server"), or try one of the many services around (push.io, UrbanAirship, Parse .. to name a few).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push notification to users, you need a **your backend environment with your certificates**. 
You also have to receive the **user device token** needed to send the push notification.

Here there is a complete tutorial to make all the necessary for push notifications: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

`NSNotification` is another thing and is **local**..in **your app**. You can use that to generate notification in your app at ***certain time*** or when a ***certain event happen***.

Comment: your backend environment with your certificate - can I find it in developer.apple.com? Or where best way to read about it?

Comment: Here there is a complete tutorial to make all the necessary for push notifications: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1